# Adding a custom UITableViewController Header in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am following along the 4th edition of iOS Programming, The Big Nerd Ranch Guide. I am using Xcode 10.0 while the book uses Xcode 5.0 and I have been deploying to a 6th generation iPad running iOS 11.0. I'm in chapter 9 and I am trying to add a custom header view for a `UITableViewController` derived class, `ItemsViewController`.

I created an empty user interface file called `HeaderView.xib`. In that file I created a `UIView` with two buttons from the interface builder. I set the File's Owner class type to `ItemsViewController`. I changed the `HeaderView`'s `UIView` size to Freeform and resized the view to be the size of the buttons. I set the `HeaderView`'s background color to clear. I have also connected the File's Owner view to the `UIView` in interface builder.

Inside of ItemsViewController I added an `IBOutlet UIView*` property to connect the `HeaderView` to the `ItemsViewController`. I wrote the `- (UIView*)headerView` instance method to load the header view bundle.

```
- (UIView*)headerView
{
    if (!_headerView)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
    }

    return _headerView;
}
```

And then in `viewDidLoad` I set the header view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    UIView* header = self.headerView;
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:header];
}
```

When I deploy and run the application, I get a black screen with the two buttons that I added. If I removed the last two lines of `viewDidLoad`, the application loads fine with some dummy data I made.

Why would the `HeaderView` overwrite all of the `ItemsViewController` display options and display a black screen?

Comment: If you are using a guide based on Xcode 5 you really should find a newer tutorial. A lot has changed.

Comment: I'm doing this because my work has apps that need maintenance and these are the materials that I have been provided. So, I'm making do with what I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue

> I have also connected the File's Owner view to the UIView in interface builder.

Since the file owner is your view controller, you are overriding the existing view which is the table. Thats why you only see the header and no table. You'd need to define another variable thats an `IBOutlet` and link the header to that instead.

Comment: Yep, yep, yep. You are correct. I made the outlet property but I connected to the existing view, not the property I made. Rookie mistake. Thank you.